# Capybara + Selenium / Webkit : Selecting *within* a div (rails / rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec, webkit, click

Good evening,

I'm trying to set up a request spec with RSpec / Capybara for a page that contains a Flot graph.  I have the page set up such that the user has to click on a marked element within the graph (tick/data point) to continue.  Obviously the graph is generated with Javascript (flot).

Is there a way to get capybara/selenium to click on a specific x/y position with the chart div?  I can measure it out in the development environment such that it should hit the datapoint in the test.

I have found ways to generate this click event with javascript:

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
```

But I don't think there is a way to get this to work in RSpec.  I'm looking for something more like:

```
find(".overlay").click(top:10px; left:50px;) # click offset from the top and left of graph div
response.body.should have_selector(# stuff that should show up on the page)
```

Not sure if it makes any difference, but I prefer Selenium over webkit at the moment so that I can see what it is doing... will switch to webkit once tests are running.

Comment: Suppose I will just manually test once in a while to make sure I haven't totally messed anything up!

Answer (score 1):

Capybara should allow you to execute Javascript from within an example when the driver supports it, e.g.:

`page.execute_script('$(document.elementFromPoint(10, 50)).click();')`

Comment: Works for me escaping the `;` with `\;` in double quotes like so: `page.execute_script("$(document.elementFromPoint(10, 50)).click()\;")`